# how to access property in object in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am receiving an json object with user details from my api request in node, 
the library uses its own each function to iterate through the object and give the details. I am trying to access specific properties in the object using (.) notation. When I try user.profile I get only the profile which is great, however user.profile.UserProfile, gives me undefined. How can I access UserProfile?
This is the code that iterates the object.

```js
const orgUsersCollection = client.listUsers();
console.log(orgUsersCollection);
orgUsersCollection.each(user => {
    console.log(user);
  })
  .then(() => console.log('All users have been listed'));
```

```html
User {
  id: '',
  status: '',
  created: '',
  activated: null,
  profile:
   UserProfile {
     firstName: '',
     lastName: '',
     login: '',
     email: '' },
  
All users have been listed
```

Comment: `user.profile` is the property, `UserProfile` is the name of the object's class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log for the object appears bit confusing. There's no property 'UserProfile' in 'user.profile'. Rather you want to write `user.profile.firstName`

```js
let user = {
  id: '',
  status: '',
  created: '',
  activated: null,
  profile: {
     firstName: 'It Works!',
     lastName: '',
     login: '',
     email: ''
  }
};
console.log(user.profile.firstName)
```

Comment: how did you know that that was just a class?